# Easy way to normalize Excel worksheets?

Tags: excel, normalization, excel-2010, vba

I have several fairly good-sized Excel worksheets (indexed by `WorksheetID`) that essentially amount to flat database tables:  rows are the records (indexed by `DataRecordID` within one worksheet), columns are the fields (indexed by `DataFieldID` within one worksheet), and the cells contain the field values (`Value`) for the appropriate records (or are blank).

I'm interested in breaking them apart to (many) records like this so that I can import them into MS Access:

`ID  |  WorksheetID  |  DataRecordID  |  DataFieldID  |  Value`

I've already done this manually.  I see that it's probably a straightforward matter to write a VBA script to chug through the sheets and (optionally) delete the records in the final table.

My question is: Before I roll up my sleeves and begin coding, is there already a built-in capability in Excel 2010 that I don't even need to write a script to do this?

Comment: Doesn't Access have some kind of normalizer built into it? I've got vague memories of having used one in the '97 version.

Comment: @Marc B You're right. Let me check into that.

Comment: @Marc B I don't think the normalization feature I saw when I imported the tables is enough.  It would let me create a separate table for each field if I wanted, but that's not quite what I need.  Good thought, though!

Comment: I can't tell for sure, but think this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10921791/melt-reshape-in-excel-using-vba

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a script for this provided the data sources are of consistent layout. The basic process is described (with pictures!) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541905/convert-matrix-to-3-column-table-reverse-pivot-unpivot-flatten-normal/20543651#20543651). However since that was considering a single matrix you will need a few extra steps:

Build in to the DataRecordIDs indication of their worksheet origins. Say with a formula such as `=A2&"|WorksheetID"` copied down to suit in a column inserted as a (new) ColumnB, for all sheets, assuming your first DataFieldID is in A2.

At Step #4 of the process (Step 2b of 3 in the Wizard) you would need to add the relevant ranges from each sheet individually.

Once you have the results Table you would then need to insert a new ColumnB and apply Text to Columns, Delimited with Other `|` to ColumnA.