# I need a Excel VBA Code to Convert a Multiple Column Table into a Single Column table

Tags: vba, excel

Input: Excel Table

```
Data    4/1/2012    4/2/2012    4/3/2012    4/4/2012    4/5/2012
V        10 20  30  40  50
H   5   10  15  20  25
S   6   12  18  24  30
R   8   16  24  32  40
A   9   18  27  36  45

Output : Excel Table
V        4/1/2012    10
V        4/2/2012    20
V        4/3/2012    30
V        4/4/2012    40
V        4/5/2012    50
H        4/1/2012    5
H        4/2/2012    10
H        4/3/2012    15
H        4/4/2012    20
H        4/5/2012    25
.
.
.
A        4/1/2012    9
A        4/2/2012    18
A        4/3/2012    27
A        4/4/2012    36
A        4/5/2012    45
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is is a site where it's expected that you will have tried to answer your question yourself and then turn to us when you get stuck. So show us what you've tried and the code that isn't working.

Comment: @chuff is right, of course. You might want to take a look at this answer:http://stackoverflow.com/q/10921791/293078.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution using `Arrays`. In the code, there are couple of *static* ranges. So you will need to set the sheet name, starting cell names accordingly.

```
Option Explicit

Sub colsToRows()
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim a As Long, lr As Long, lc As Long
Dim va As Variant, vd As Variant
Dim LastRow As Long, LastCol As Long

        '-- set e.g. sheet name Sheet1, starting column = B, dates starting cell = C2
        Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
        LastRow = ws1.Range("B" & ws1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        LastCol = ws1.Cells(Range("C2").Row, ws1.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column - 1

        '--put dates into this array as it repeats for each item
        vd = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ws1.Range("C2").Resize(1, LastCol - 1)))

        '-- titles
        ws1.Range("B2").Offset(LastRow + 1) = "Item"
        ws1.Range("C2").Offset(LastRow + 1) = "Dates"
        ws1.Range("D2").Offset(LastRow + 1) = "Data"

        '--2 is deducted as the main range is starting from B3. So B3-B1 = 2
        For a = 1 To LastRow - 2
           '--to get next last row
            lr = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

            '--items
            va = Array(ws1.Range("B2").Offset(a).Value)
            ws1.Range("B1").Offset(lr).Resize(LastCol - 1) = Application.Transpose(va)

            '--dates
            ws1.Range("C1").Offset(lr).Resize(UBound(vd)) = Application.Transpose(vd)

            '--data
            va = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ws1.Range("C2").Offset(a).Resize(1, LastCol - 1)))
            ws1.Range("D1").Offset(lr).Resize(UBound(va)) = Application.Transpose(va)
        Next a

End Sub
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: bonCodigo@gmail.com - Hi Sir,... The code worked... I was able to convert the data.... Thanks for the help. You helped me at the right time. Great help.

Comment: @VishnuvinodhBalasundaram glad you got it worked `=)` specially given the cell references that you need to do. But can assure you, this is faster than iterating over cells ;) If everything is alright, please accept the answer by clicking on the tick near upvoting buttons.

Comment: anyway to do the opposite?

Comment: @Wilson Single column to multiple column? Have you tried out the opposite?