# Specific transpose in Excel 2010

Tags: excel, transpose

I would like to transform this:

```
id  brand color price
1   bmw   white 100
2   fiat  black 200
3   audi  blue  300
```

into this

```
id  value
1   bmw
1   white
1   100
2   fiat
2   black
2   200
3   audi
3   blue
3   300
```

Headers (id, title...) are not important, all I need are values.

I've been searching for a solution for some time now, but can't find any.

Thanks for you help!

Comment: Take a look at this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10921791/293078). You could run something like it and then delete the Header column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with Excel formulas. Assuming that your data are in cells 'A2:D4' and that your results begin cell F2, the following OFFSET formulas will transform the data as you want:

The first formula would begin in cell F2. This is the formula that gets and repeats the id:

```
  =OFFSET($A$1,INT((ROW(F2)-ROW($F$2))/3+1),0)
```

The second formula would begin in cell G2. This one traverses the columns of the data:

```
  =OFFSET($B$1,F2,MOD(ROW(F2)-ROW($F$2),3))
```

Both would be copied down as far as would be needed to transpose all the data.

[image: Excel sheet display]