# Specific Transpose in Excel

Tags: excel, transpose

I would like to do the opposite of what this person wants to do.

[Specific transpose in Excel 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16919365/specific-transpose-in-excel-2010)

Transpose backwards in effect.

It would be nice to have a "how to do the opposite/reverse" button on stackoverflow.

In the mean time I will be trying to reverse the code given as a solution to the question asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set up the data like below:

[image]

In column E, I just auto-filled numbers until I reached the highest number in Column A. Then I used the following formulas in the cells indicated and auto-filled down from there.

F5:

```
=OFFSET($B$1,(($E5-1)*3+0),0)
```

G5:

```
=OFFSET($B$1,(($E5-1)*3+1),0)
```

H5:

```
=OFFSET($B$1,(($E5-1)*3+2),0)
```

The *3 should reflect the number of categories you have (here: brand, color, price). To add additional columns, just keep increasing the number that's added immediately after *3 in each category column.

I should note, this is only going to work if your data really is just like the example, with consecutive numeric identifiers for each item starting at 1.