# Need a macro or a way to create list from Excel table

Tags: macos, list, excel, vba

I am working on distance related table and I would like to add it to mysql database but need it to be in a different format than the table itself.

Here is the table

```
                MANH    BONX    BROK    QUNZ    STIS    Loc1    Loc2    Loc3
ABINGTONCT       360     360     390     380     400     380     390     435
ADDISONCT        285     285     310     300     325     300     310     355
```

Need it to be in this format

```
    MANH    ABINGTONCT       360
    MANH    ADDISONCT        285
    BONX    ABINGTONCT       360
    BONX    ADDISONCT        285
    BROK    ABINGTONCT       390
    BROK    ADDISONCT        310
```

Comment: This answer of mine looks relevant, although not sure if everything will run in Mac VBA: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10922351/293078

Comment: no idea how vb works so your solution just went over my head :)

Comment: Ah well. Since you tagged as `macros`, I thought you were open to a VBA solution. There are formula solutions out there on SO. Try searching on "normalizing."

Comment: Or better yet "normalize". Good luck :)