# Convert columns of categories into multiple rows in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet of Chamber of Commerce members that looks like this:

```
COMPANY              CATEGORY 1             CATEGORY 2       CATEGORY 3
Ameriprise           Lending Institutions   Banks
Country Inn          Lodging                Hotels           Bed & Breakfast
FirstBanc            Lending Institutions   Banks
Gillespie Fair       Events                 Festivals
```

That I need to convert—on a new sheet—into this:

```
COMPANY              CATEGORY
Ameriprise           Banks
Ameriprise           Lending Institutions
Country Inn          Bed & Breakfast
Country Inn          Hotels
Country Inn          Lodging
Firstbanc            Banks
Firstbanc            Lending Institutions
Gillespie Fair       Events
Gillespie Fair       Festivals
```

In a nutshell, I need to produce multiple entries for the Company for every Category that business falls under. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is a pretty frequently asked type of question. Here's one very complete answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20800915/293078. I've also written a VBA solution that might be of interest:http://stackoverflow.com/a/10922351/293078

Answer (score 0):

In data cleaning world, we call this reshaping a data frame from wide to long.

And there's a way to do it in Excel.

1. Hit this key combination: `Alt D P`. This will bring up PivotTable Wizard (Yup, not many know this.)
2. Select `Multiple consolidation ranges`. Click next.
3. Select `I will create the page fields`. Click next.
4. Select your data range. Click next.
5. Select the location to show to pivot table. Click next.
6. You'll see a pivot table appearing. In  the PivotTable Field List, untick `Row` and `Column`.
7. You should be left with `count of value` and a number. Double click that cell. You'll see a new sheet with your converted data table.